# Instruments complains of a leak, but object is clearly alloced and dealloced

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm baffled by instruments complaining of a leak with xmlParser.
Its a local object thats alloced and dealloced. There seems to be nothing fancy that i can see that might cause it to leak.

```
#import "WebServiceAPI.h"
#import "XMLParser.h"

@implementation WebServiceAPI

-(void) getRadioStationList//:(id) aDelegate;
{

    NSData *xml = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL  
URLWithString:@"http://radio.com/Fradio/Radios.xml"]];
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xml];

    parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];
    [xmlParser parse];

    [xmlParser setDelegate:nil];


    [xmlParser release];        
}
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
{
}        

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection*) connection didFailWithError:(NSError*) error
{
    //NSLog(@" Connection for radiolist failed ");
}        

-(void) dealloc
{

    parser = nil;
    [parser release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Here is the stack trace if its of any use.

```
   5 Footy Radio      48 Bytes  -[WebServiceAPI getRadioStationList] 
   4 CoreFoundation      48 Bytes  +[NSObject(NSObject) alloc]
   3 CoreFoundation      48 Bytes  +[NSObject(NSObject) allocWithZone:]
   2 libobjc.A.dylib      48 Bytes  class_createInstance
   1 libobjc.A.dylib      48 Bytes  _internal_class_createInstanceFromZone
   0 libSystem.B.dylib      48 Bytes  calloc
```

Can somebody shed some light as to what maybe the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `getRadioStationList` should just be `radioStationList`;  `get*` has a very particular implication in iOS and this ain't it.

Secondly, this makes no sense:

```
parser = nil;
[parser release];
```

That second line of code does nothing and, hence, the `parser` will be leaked.

Comment: if i remove the parser = nil; then the app crashes immediately. Have you some advise as to what should be done to clean up the parser mem since I cannot dealloc it, maybe because its set as a delegate.

Comment: There is definitely some something wrong with the pay I am handling parser. Even it if make it a locally declared object XMLParser *parser = [[[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser]autorelease]; it causes the app to crash. But if i remove the autorelease it wont crash. But that doesn't seem like a solution.

Comment: Do you manipulate the parser anywhere else? That it is the delegate is irrelevant.  The xmlParser is long gone.  Also, make sure you understand why the nil assignment changes the behavior....

Comment: What is XMLParser and how is it implemented? Sounds like it is over releasing something internally.  What does Build and Analyze say?

Answer (score 0):

If `getRadioStationList` is called more than dealloc it could leak `parser` because `parser` would be overwritten with newly alloced data.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, from your question, the problem is with xmlParser right?
Although instruments shows the leak at xmlParser, the leak is actually in the rest of your parser methods, ie. didStartElement, didEndElement, etc.

Secondly, you should not set nil then release, since what you are releasing is just 'nil'. Remove that line.

Thirdly, with regards to parser, you have a reference count problem here. parser is a delegate, so it will be used when xmlParser is ready to call it. This may occur after you release parser in your code above, causing the crash. What you may have to do is to retain the parser in parserDidStartDocument and release it in parserDidEndDocument.
It may also be possible that you are releasing your WebServiceAPI too soon, causing the dealloc to occur prematurely. It is important to note that you should only release when you are completely done with the object and you should retain an object that you would like to use, especially if you know it may get released by some other process.